# How do I detect if Edge Browser input corruption bug has been patched

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge, browser-detection

Recently Edge browser had a bug with `<option>` elements with the `value` attribute omitted.

```
<select name="qty">
  <option>1</option>
  <option>2</option>
</select>
```

Affected Edge browsers inject random characters into the form data: `qty=1Q` or `qty=2Җ` or worse `qty=29`

Microsoft pushed a fix in July their [issue #1747791](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/17477791/) in the [July RS4 Windows 10 Update, kb4338819](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4338819/windows-10-update-kb4338819).  With this fix, they did not increment the browser version number, `17.17134`.  They instead incremented the Operating System Build number to `17134.165`

An application I support continues to receive bug reports from users with old versions of Edge.  I would like to detect a user with the affected browser and display a warning.

The broken and fixed versions of Edge both report the same version number in the UserAgent string, `17.17134`.  Is there another way to detect the build of Edge, or the OS Build number?

How do I detect if this Edge Browser input corruption bug has been patched?

Comment: Does same issue exist if you try getting value of select with JS? And why not just set `value` on <option>

Comment: I had considered this, but have no way to test for it.  I no longer have a windows installation available with the affected Edge Browser version, and have found no solution for creating that test environment.

Comment: Only suggestion I have is show  message for that build with suggestion user uses another browser or whatever you deem reasonable. And make sure server side validation catches it also

Comment: Good thinking -- I have already done this, but have been tasked to find a more targeted solution

Comment: Another would be post a dummy off screen form into hidden iframe target when that user agent is encountered and validate it without needing user interaction on page load. Then use postMessage to tell parent if problems exist. Wonder if days of IE hacks will ever end!!

Comment: Why not just set `value` on <option>:  There are thousands of occurrences of <option> in the application.  Auditing them all is beyond my given scope for this problem

Comment: That audit of missing `value` as well as fix could also be done client side with script if it is causing the problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing I would do is audit missing `value` on `<option>` using javascript if that is the root of the problem as seems to be mentioned in link you posted.

Then , if you have no way to sniff the differences in user agent one way to test would be to programmatically (javascript) submit an off-screen form into an off screen or hidden iFrame target when that user agent is encountered.

This would be done  on page load with no user interaction

Then validate server side and return a page to the iframe with a [`postMessage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) call that would tell parent page if problem exists or not.

Will require postMessage event listener in parent also.

Both the form and iframe could be inserted into dom using script on as needed basis

Comment: And since this version of Edge should support ServiceWorker, it might also be possible to do this without the need for a call to server.

Answer (score 0):

Adapted solution from @charlietfl

A hidden iframe is presented only when the user has the affected
useragent.  Today, this includes up to date Edge browsers, but
in October the version in the UserAgent should increment again.

Rather than interact back to the parent window, the iframe opens
to a page that can access the user session.  It presents a HTML form
of the type affected by the bug, and immediately posts itself.
The POST data is checked for corruption, and results made available
to the user session.

The rather obvious javascript (with jquery) looks a bit like this:

```
  % if ( $do_check ) {
    <iframe id="edge_browser_check_iframe" style="display:none;"></iframe>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      if ( /Edge\/17\.17134/.test( navigator.userAgent )) {
        $("#edge_browser_check_iframe").attr(
          'src',
          'edge_browser_check-iframe.html'
        );
      }
    </script>
  % }
```

Answer (score -2):

A work around can be create JavaScript function to detect the Edge browser and it's version while user opens the site.

If it is a problematic version then inform user to use other browser and do not allow any further interaction.

If it is any other version of Edge then let the user to use the site.

Regards

Deepak

Comment: The question is ***How do I** detect if this Edge Browser input corruption bug has been patched?*. Your answer is *Try to [detect if this Edge Browser input corruption bug has been patched]*...